# Why does this image resize on hover, when it is less than 100% wide (in FF21)?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive image which transitions on hover. When the image is at 100% width, the hover transition works fine. However, in FF21, when you shrink the browser window down to a size where the image starts shrinking, and then hover over the image, at some sizes there is a small but perceptible shift upwards (of the background image). It is a very small shift, and it doesn't occur at every width (strangely).

*Screenshot with the two states below (light area without, and dark area with hover). The bug is most clearly seen at the 'x'. The effect only occurs at certain widths (not all) and is very small. But still, it is clearly there.*

[image: Example of the bug]

I've tried IE and Chrome as well, and they don't show this behavior. So it seems to be FF specific. It looks like it's resizing the image to be 1px less high. Does anyone know why that is, and how to fix it? (jfiddle link below so you can see for yourself)

http://jsfiddle.net/t3Djd/1/

HTML

```
<body>
  <figure>
      <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
      <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x450" /></a>
  </figure>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
}

/*========================================
============== CENTER IMAGES =============
========================================*/

body {
    text-align: center;
}

/*========================================
=========== RESPONSIVE IMAGES ============
========================================*/

figure, figure > a, img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*========================================
============ GENERAL STYLING =============
========================================*/

figure h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.75rem; /* 16 x 1.75 = 28px */
    font-weight: normal;
}

figure h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

/*========================================
============ HOVER TRANSITION ============
========================================*/

figure {
    padding: 1rem 1rem 2rem;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

figure h2 {
    margin: -1rem 0 0 -1rem; /* offset the figure padding */
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
}

figure h2 a {
    z-index: 1;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

figure:hover h2 a {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

figure > a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
    background: black;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px black;
}

img {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

figure:hover img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Stop deleting your questions and re-posting them

Comment: @Pete, I re-posted it because I changed it so much that I thought it would be clearer as a new question. Thought it would be tidier. And I don't need the attitude Pete, you can just tell me nicely if you have something to say.

Comment: @Pete, it is a bit rude though. Just preface it with please when you're ordering people to do things on the internet. It'll make it all seem a lot nicer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug using firefox, the issue has already been brought up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403662/how-to-prevent-imghover-rounding-wobbling-firefox-only)

And here is the link to the [Firefox Bug Report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745549)

Apparent fix:
applying `box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em;` to the css `img` tag

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've also seen that when the bug occurs on hover, a black border appears at the bottom of the image. I'll see if I can figure out why that is..

Comment: Maybe it's a rounding error in the resizing. Which would explain why it only occurs at certain widths (at less than 100%), and why it's only 1px at the bottom. Don't understand why it would only occur at hover though..

Comment: Known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403662/how-to-prevent-imghover-rounding-wobbling-firefox-only

Comment: Aha! Wow, that's an obscure bug. I've tried applying `box-shadow: #000 0em 0em 0em;` to the `<img>`, and that fixes it. Thank you very much Dylan!